# Can developers remove Apple Store and Google Play's latest Production build?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-play, app-store

I'm planning for an update release on the Apple and Google Play Stores. I have had both apps approved and all it takes is pressing the release button.

My iOS and Android apps are both on Production now. If the new update fails, I would like to fallback to the previous version i.e., removing the latest version, and moving one to the past.

Can this be done on any store?

Comment: On the App Store you would need to release a new version. You can't go back to an older version

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was inherently the norm but I wasn't sure about reversion.